# Fade out when user leaves page — jquery

Tags: jquery, fade, fadeout, fadein

I have some simple page transitions that fade in, once the user has landed. However, I'm also trying to make the same page fade out, when the user leaves.

I have found a few solutions, but they appeared to use delay(). Are there any that don't?

Thanks for any help, (I'm new to this, mind!)

Tom :)

I am currently using this code:

```
  $(document).ready(
    function(){

    $( 'body' ).fadeIn(2000);   

        $('#stop').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); });

     $('#clients').click(function() { 
        $("#projectinfo").slideUp('slow');
$("#us").fadeOut('slow');
   $("ul").fadeToggle('slow'); });

   $('#information').click(function() { 
        $("#projectinfo").slideUp('slow');
$("ul").fadeOut('slow');
   $("#us").fadeToggle('slow'); });

     $('#question').click(function() { 
   $("#projectinfo").slideToggle('slow'); });

        $('#question').hover(function() { 
   $("#projectinfo").slideToggle('slow'); });

   $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    function redirectPage() {




});
```

Comment: ... and are you talking about a page as a document that will be closed by the browser as the user closes the tab or window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER:

you will need to finish your `redirectPage()` function to something like this:

```
   $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage(linkLocation));      
    });

    function redirectPage(link) {
        document.location.href= link;
    }
```

@sharethis, thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Seeing his code I think that he wants to catch link clicks, prevent the default page changing first, fade out the body then, and finally change the page with javascript.